# Assigning a Setting to a Variable and Using it in an if Statement

Tags: options, variables

Is it possible to assign

```
get_theme_mod('dds') !=='false';
```

to a variable and include it in an if statement instead of typing the whole thing?

This is the if statement I am dealing with:

```
$DDS = get_theme_mod('dds')!=='false';

if(is_category() && $DDS) :
    //output some css style
endif;
```

I get an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'`

Comment: Fix the first line of your `if` statement. `if(is_category() && $DDS :` to `if(is_category() && $DDS )`

Comment: my bad, that wasn't the reason why I get the error though

Comment: @GregMcMullen Actually, it was... I feel dump. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE*: Per your comment, DDS means *Disable Dynamic Style* and is true when enabled, so I have modified the function accordingly. check for -> `if ( is_category() && ! $DDS ) :`

---

Short answer, **yes** you can use a variable representing this function `get_theme_mod('dds')`

Now I don't know what will be the result of that function, so consider checking what is [considered false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) when converting to a bool.  To sum it up, empty strings, arrays objects and 0 are considered `false`, every non zero number (positive or negative) and non empty strings, arrays, objects will be considered `true`.

so you can have

```
$DDS = ! empty( get_theme_mod('dds') ) ? get_theme_mod('dds') : false ;
```

which uses the [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to set the variable and then your `if` statement

```
if ( is_category() && ! $DDS ) :
  // Print CSS Style
endif;
```

*NOTE*

using the syntax `if endif;` is best when you have long functions, because you can visually see when the `if` ends, so it improves readability. Also when using a lot of HTML within your PHP, it provides the same benefits of readability.  But in the end, it's a question of preferences.

**EDIT**

I just noticed another fault with your logic when assigning your `$DDS` variable. You are essentially storing into that variable,  the results of a check. You are saying `get_theme_mod('dds')` is not false, so it's true, and it will always be!

if you want to work with the actual value of that function, you need to use the ternary operator as I have provided.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. DDS is short for 'disable dynamic styles', I use it with every other setting before outputting any styles to the head of the document. So if DDS equals true (which means do not include any styles in document head) no css is outputted and the user will just have to settle with the default styles included in the style sheet.

Comment: ok, then your logic doesn't work. you are actually saying, `if is_category=true AND DDS=true then print CSS` but DDS means disabled, so you should have `if is_category=true AND DDS=not_true then print CSS`

Comment: @FabianAmran I have updated the answer to reflect the changes